# Trying to Insert an Image with EF-CodeFirst SqlServerCE

Tags: ef-code-first, sql-server-ce

with standard sqlserver, I can use codefirst and create a column type of Image and I can insert blob type data. With SqlServerCE I believe I need to use the binary type.  I can't figure out how to put byte[] (c#) to the binary type.

My codefirst declaration is this:

public Binary ImageData { get; set; }

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hello i don't know if you already but two things image is going to be deprecated, and you can do it by:

```
> public myClass {
>   //image for the logo
>      public byte[] Logo { get; set; }
>   }
```

and use varbinary:

> modelBuilder.Entity().Property(p => p.Logo).HasColumnName("Logo").HasMaxLength(Length).HasColumnType("varbinary");